# Django nested 'with' and 'block' tag

Tags: django

I have **base.html** template like this:

```
<p>{% block a %}{% endblock %}</p>
<p>{% block b %}{% endblock %}</p>
```

And **index.html** template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% with description="foo" %}
  {% block a %}{{ description }}{% endblock %}
  {% block b %}{{ description }}{% endblock %}
{% endwith %}
```

But the result becomes:

```
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

Instead of:

```
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 5):

Not in the way you'd like it to, in inherited templates django looks for code inside of `blocks` which means it won't recognize the existence of your `with` block outside of this. so your only option is to include the with inside each block

```
{% block a %}    
    {% with description="foo" %}
        {{ description }}
    {% endwith %}    
{% endblock %}
```

Although for a single call it isn't worth using the `with`, the only other option is to pass `description` through the context

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**: It doesn't work as I expected for my particular case. See comments.

After reading Sayse's answer and understanding better how blocks work, I've come with this solution:

base.html:

```
{% block wrapping_block %}
    {% block a %}
    {% endblock %}

    {% block b %}
    {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

index.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block wrapping_block %}
    {% with description='foo' %}
        {% block a %}
            {{ description }}
        {% endblock %}

        {% block b %}
            {{ description }}
        {% endblock %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Very interesting approach, I'm surprised it works, I'm guessing its because you're defining a block to be used for things that inherit from `index.html`. I do still wonder what `description` is actually used for but glad you found something that works!

Comment: The problem with this one is that anything inside 'wrapping_block' and outside of 'a' and 'b' is being stripped out in the sub-templates. Just realised now... ooops!

Comment: I'm trying to use the same values for the meta tags and the Open Graph tags, like title and description. In some pages, this is defined in the template and are a few words long. I wanted to use a variable to keep it consistent. I guess that I have to repeat it after all.

Comment: Potentially yes, where does the *value* of description come from though? I still don't understand why this needs to be done inside of a block and not just done in the base template

Comment: The values of say "description" are not in the context, are hardcoded in the template and each subpage has a different description.